# Create dynamic coloramp with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

It is possible to create a style with default color but with variable quantity with GeoServer?

I've a lot of grids that reproduce surface temperature. I don't know previously the minimum and maximun temperature but I would like to use Magma colormap from QGIS.

My aim is divide in ten classes the variability of temperature like this:

> (MaxTemperature - MinTemperature) / 10

Then, with this classes I need to obtain a dynamic coloramp.

Something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267630/dynamic-label-in-sld-style) but I've no clear what is `${env`

Now I'm be able to use a JSON from GeoSever with which I can create a legend from the styles with OpenLayers and I hope that is possible to do the same thing also whit the dynamic coloramp.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the [SLD REST Service](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html), it allows you to [classify raster data](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/sldservice/index.html#classify-raster-and-vector-data) based on it's values. You can then include the SLD returned as a style for your layer as a [`SLD` parameter](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#external-styles) in the WMS request.

Comment: Ok, I have never used GeoServer REST and I need to learn how it works before accept your answer