# Multi-language label in colormap SLD (GeoServer)

Tags: geoserver, sld, internationalization

I would try to make my colormap available in different languages. In the documentation from the GeoServer and GeoTools I can't find any opportunity to do that.

In the "standard" SLD with `FeatureStyleType` I can do the following and it works:

```
 <Title>This is the default title
  <Localized lang="en">English title</Localized>
  <Localized lang="it">Titolo in italiano</Localized>
 </Title>
```

For the `Colormap` I have the following structure:

```
  <sld:ColorMap>
   <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#006837" label="English label" opacity="1.0" quantity="6"/>
  </sld:ColorMap>
```

I found an article about dynamisation for the parameter with CQL:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rastersymbolizer.html#cql-expressions
[Dynamic label in SLD Style](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267630/dynamic-label-in-sld-style)

This works well for single parameter but if I try to add a language parameter in the WMS request I can't depict it with the colormap. Does anybody know if there is a way to use i18n with the colormap label? If there is no chance to do it, is there another way to create a colorramp with multilanguage support?